# How to get the Path difference and store it in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, variable

Suppose I have two paths. Path1 which is static and path2 which is dynamic.

Example:

- Path1= /tmp/folder/
- Path2= /tmp/folder/dir1/dir1_2

Result:

- Diff= /dir/dir1_2

I want to achieve as above example.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `realpath`, you can do:

```
$ Path1=/tmp/folder
$ Path2=/tmp/folder/dir1/dir1_2
$ realpath -m --relative-to="$Path1" -- "$Path2"
dir1/dir1_2
```

In  POSIX/Korn-like shells (such as bash), store in a variable with:

```
Diff=$(realpath -m --relative-to="$Path1" -- "$Path2")
```

with the usual caveat that it doesn't work properly if the resulting path ends in newline characters.

With `zsh` or a non-interactive `bash -O lastpipe`:

```
realpath -zm --relative-to="$Path1" -- "$Path2" |
  IFS= read -rd '' Diff
```

Can be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply interested in subtracting one string from another then you could pipe the longer string into a sed command to remove the shorter substring:

```
$ echo $Path2 | sed "s,$Path1,,g"
dir1/dir1_2
```

You need to use double quotes for sed. Also since both strings have / character in them you need to change the default delimiter for sed to something else, Here we have used comma instead.